# PHP Merge array to another sub array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge an array to another sub array. The code as below:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'id' => array(),
    'data' => array(
        'rows' => array(
            array('name'=>'abc123'),
            array('name'=>'abc456'),
            array('name'=>'abc789'),        
        )   
    )
);


$temp = array(
   array('name'=>'def123'),
   array('name'=>'def456'),
   array('name'=>'def789')      
);

$data['data']['rows'] += $temp;

var_dump($data);
```

However it didn't work. I also try with array_merge but it is still the same. The only solution I can come up is using for-loop, but I don't want to use an addition for-loop.

Comment: I try to add data in $temp to 'rows'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging the arrays will work with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), but you have to remember to use the return-value of the function:

```
$data['data']['rows'] = array_merge($data['data']['rows'], $temp);
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/mSZjugNT)

Comment: Sorry, It is what I need. :|

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$data['data']['rows'] = array_merge($data['data']['rows'], $temp);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/73560)